# How do I use the Pandas module to read the first columns of a csv file into a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I am an undergrad working a data structures class. I am fairly new to the pandas module and I want to use it in my assignment to read the first column of multiple rows of a csv file into a list. This may seem simple to some of you professional programmers but I cant rap my head around it and a friend of mine told me to use the Pandas frame work. I have been trying to use it and have this code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\fskid\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Data Structures Fall 2023\\Homework Five Python\\SportsTeamsOne.csv')
list1 = df1[df1.columns[1]].tolist()

df2 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\fskid\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Data Structures Fall 2023\\Homework Five Python\\SportsTeamsTwo.csv')
list2 = df2[df2.columns[1]].tolist()

df3 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\fskid\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Data Structures Fall 2023\\Homework Five Python\\SportsTeamsThree.csv')
list3 = df3[df3.columns[1]].tolist()


print (list1)
print(list2)
print(list3)
```

When I print however I get the same list repeated, I assume it has something to do with the already created panda data frame and I am trying to figure it out on my own but I struggle with debugging and problem solving overall. Could anyone help to walk me through it and kind of give me an idea on how you use problem solving to figure it out so in the future I can do it on my own? Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To get help on Stack Overflow, you need to read the announcements  and think about **how to ask.**  I will give link to you about most important announcements. [minimal-reproducible-example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Read it and revise your questions so that you can have a good experience on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code except for a small bug:
use `column[0]` to stand for the first column instead of `column[1]`.

Knowing thay you say you "get the same list repeated", I am guessing that your real requirement is to iterate the list. To iterate the list, try:

```
for i in list1:
    print(i)
```

If you have any questions, feel free to ask. Hope this could help you!

Comment: That helps! What I mean by that is that when I convert each Dataframe to a list. I get three separate lists, one from each csv file, but when I print off the three separate lists it just prints off the same one.